# Should vertex data be laid out on per-pertex or per-attribute basis?

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex

I have a piece of OpenGL code that renders meshes. I use VBOs to render them. Now, meshes consist of vertices that have the following attributes:

```
glm::vec3 position;
glm::vec2 uv;
glm::vec4 color;
glm::vec3 normal;
glm::vec3 tangent;
glm::vec3 binormal;
```

Currently, I render the vertices on per-vertex basis like this:

```
// Upload a vector of vertices
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, &m_vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Set the "layout" of the vertex attributes
// Binormal
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*) (sizeof(glm::vec3) * 3 + sizeof(glm::vec2) + sizeof(glm::vec4)));
// Tangent
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*) (sizeof(glm::vec3) * 2 + sizeof(glm::vec2) + sizeof(glm::vec4)));
// Normal
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*) (sizeof(glm::vec3) + sizeof(glm::vec2) + sizeof(glm::vec4)));
// Color
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*) (sizeof(glm::vec3) + sizeof(glm::vec2)));
// UV
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*) (sizeof(glm::vec3)));
// Position
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*) 0);

// Draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Now, I've seen people do it a bit differently. Some upload all the vertex positions first, then the UV data, then normals and so on. To do a rough visualization of the data layout:

```
// P = position, U = uv, N = normal

// Per-vertex layout
PUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUNPUN

// Per-attribute layout
PPPPPPPPPPPPUUUUUUUUUUUUNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Is there any difference between these two layouts? Is one or the other causing any performance issues, especially if data gets updated constantly?

Comment: "especially if data gets updated constantly" Are you really sure you need that? Most computations can be done in the vertex shader (transformations, animations, ...). But if you really need to upload them in every frame, I guess that's pretty much your bottleneck anyway. Otherwise, "per-attribute" can be a bit faster if some of your shaders don't need all attributes, and even if it is not the case it might be a *very* little bit faster due to some alignment / caching, but that's hardware dependent.

Comment: The alignment / caching thing is what made me wonder in the first place. What if all attributes are needed? Could that make per-vertex layout faster instead as all the needed data for the current vertex is "right there"?

Comment: @manabreak that's right. The per-vertex layout is fast because the vertex fetch unit has an easier job getting vertex data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first layout you're describing is typically called "interleaved", and is mostly considered advantageous. The reasoning is that it results in more local memory access patterns, which are more cache friendly.

One good reason to use a different layout would be if some of the attributes are updated much more frequently than others. In the extreme case, where some of them are static, while others are updated frequently, it might actually be beneficial to keep the static attributes in one VBO, with `GL_STATIC_DRAW` usage, and use a separate buffer with `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` usage for the attributes that change frequently.

@leemes brings up another interesting case in a comment above: If you often use only a subset of the attributes for draw calls, it might also be worth grouping them differently. In that case, you could have the attributes that are always used in an interleaved layout, and keep the more rarely used ones separate.

With all that said, you will often have bigger bottlenecks in your rendering pipeline, so the difference might be difficult to measure outside targeted synthetic benchmarks. Still, I think it's mostly worth it to keep everything as streamlined as possible. Particularly since most computers/devices run on battery power these days, where you don't want to waste anything.